# Bootable Low Level Format Tool

Tags: formatting, repair, hard-drive, bootable-media

I am looking for a bootable low level format tool, specifically for an old maxtor HDD (ATA). I remember that long time ago I repaired a disk with such a tool, but now, googling i only find Windows based formatting tools.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to a windows machine to burn a CD with the rescue tool? If so, the MaxBlast tool at http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=3.4.0.1.1&vgnextoid=3b17fbbad0f89210VgnVCM1000001a48090aRCRD will probably do what you need.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/277394/what-is-the-dos-debug-script-to-low-level-format-a-hard-drive/277395#277395    Looks like  for this, the hard drive has to be <=2GB ! and hard drive has to be <=1024 cylinders!

Comment: The term "low level format" has a specific meaning that I suspect you are not aware of, and so you are using the term incorrectly.  Modern hard disks can not be low level formatted outside of the factory.  You should clarify what you mean when you say "low level format".

Answer (score 2):

I use this particular liveCD all the time at work.
It provides several diagnostic tools that would certainly be of help.  It also has a Low Level Formatting Tool that would work for what you are trying to accomplish.
I hope it works for you!
[UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the BIOS has a low level formatting tool built in. Have you tried having a look at this? Did you just want to format it or did you want to install something afterards, as some windows version can create startup disks that have basic DOS capabilities that you can use to format the drive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted is a formatting tool that is available in a "live", bootable form. Take a look at their [web site](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

Answer (score 0):

There's a chap who goes by the handle Tmod who has a really useful [Utilities Disk](http://forums.overclockersclub.com/index.php?showtopic=101851&st=0) that I've been using for years. It boots into a DOS-type environment. I use it quite often to do zeroing out of HDDs.

After that I'd use the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to do the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For securely wiping the harddrive,

[http://www.dban.org/](http://www.dban.org)